# React Redux object Array value not update in component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am trying to update object array item value but reducer is updated not rendering in Component...
Can u please help for this

```
case actionTypes.UPDATE_MAGAZINE_BOOKMARK:
  const arrayObj = state.magazineListDetail;
  const updateMagazine = state.magazineListDetail.data
    .map(function(x) {
      return x.id;
    })
    .indexOf(action.magazineList);
  let newMagazineArray = [...state.magazineListDetail.data];
  newMagazineArray[updateMagazine] = {
    ...newMagazineArray[updateMagazine],
    isBookmark: !newMagazineArray[updateMagazine].isBookmark
  };
  arrayObj.data = newMagazineArray;
  return {
    ...state,
    magazineListDetail: newMagazineArray
  };
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Take out the two lines with `arrayObj` in it and retry, they seem to be doing some state mutation.

Comment: Probably something wrong with component